# Plot data time in a cell array X values in double in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I had a list of data and time in Excel, imported to Matlab using:

```
[~,str,~] = xlsread('time_sheet.xlsx','b:b');
```

the string came in a 964080 x 1 "cell" array.

I want to be able to pick an interval within this cell array like something:

```
interval_time = str(1:670);
```

I need to plot it against "double" data (to show values in time).

I am not managing to plot it..

Can someone help me, please? Sorry for the question but I am very new to matlab.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have integer data stored as strings in an `964080 x 1` cell array. You want to plot these as integers on the y-axis against another variable with `double` values on the x-axis. Is this correct? I think you should update your question and make it clear.

Comment: the cell array to the x axis is from excel in date format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss), and it is importing only as strong (i tried num, raw, both..)... The Y axis is from power demand values, stored as double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just manage to make it. I was going the wrong way by importing it from Excel.

I made a

```
t1 = datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
t2 = datetime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 45, 0);
t = t1:minutes(15):t2;
```

and was straightforward for using in the X axis.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you attempt to do should be something like:

```
interval_time = cellfun(@str2num,str{1:670})
```

but I am not sure about the format of strings in `str`, so this code is just as hint

Comment: I attempted to import the whole date interval (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss) from excel to plot in X axis, and plot it against double values in Y axis.
the interval selection will be ok once I manage to plot the whole data. But it says the first input to plot (the date) is not valid. It was working fine when I had the number of samples (integers) on the X axis, but doesnt work with date in this format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss) from excel. my samples of date have 15 min interval. Maybe I can recreate the datetime serie on matlab using a 15 min interval from a beginning date?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the labels of the x-axis

```
dates = {'2019-12-04','2019-12-05','2019-12-06','2019-12-08','2019-12-09'}

Y = [1:5]

your_selected_range = [2:4]
X = your_selected_range


plot(Y(X),X, 'LineWidth',5')

% // XTickLabel will change the labels to your dates
set(gca, 'XTick',X, 'XTickLabel',{dates{X}},'FontSize',20)
```

[image]